# How can I tag friends in a YouTube video on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, youtube, facebook-tags

I've shared a video from YouTube to Facebook, and this has shown up ok on my wall.

Now I want to tag friends that are in the video, and can't see any option to do that. All the guides I see in places like [this](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=833) say that there should be a tag option to the lower right of the video, but I can't see that. Is this a feature we've lost in one of their updates, or has it just moved somewhere obscure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tagging is available only if you upload the video directly to Facebook—if you share the link, the video is fetched from YouTube, not Facebook so you can't tag them.

Might I suggest dropping a comment and doing an `@Mention`?

Answer (score 1):

Click "Share" under the video on YouTube then click on the Facebook icon—a little window should come up. In that window, there is a small box that says "Whats on your mind"; in it type `@friends` name.

For example `@candice ramkissoon`.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the link of the video then go to your Facebook profile and paste it there then write your friends name but start with capital!

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is when you are about to share the video is: is the name of you friend is writing with capital letter you will have to start with the capital letter, there is a difference when you type with a regular word, so I suggest you to do it just exactly like they have it on their profile, good luck

Answer (score -2):

Copy/paste the link address from Facebook directly in *What’s in your mind* box, then you can tag.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot, to clarify your answer?